# Wrong data copied to struct from void pointer

Tags: c

Ok so I've run out of things to try and fix this.

I've got a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
   u8int  NodeType;
   u32int Group;
   u32int Direction;
   u16int ID;

} tsTargetNode;


void vTrackNode(const uint8 *pu8Val, uint8 u8Len, void *pvCbData)
{
   /* Copy data */
   memcpy(pvCbData, pu8Val, u8Len);

   /* Doing this gives the wrong data */
   //tsTargetNode *node = (tsTargetNode *) pvCbData;  

   /* Doing this gives the right data */
   memcpy(&tsTargetNode.NodeType, pvCbData, 1);
   memcpy(&tsTargetNode.Group, pvCbData+1, 4);
   memcpy(&tsTargetNode.Direction, pvCbData+1+4, 4);
   memcpy(&tsTargetNode.ID, pvCbData+1+4+4, 2);
}
```

For example:
Data passed *pu8Val = 0x AA BB CC DD EE FF 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00

using pointer, the data I retrieved is:

```
NodeType  = 0xAA
Group     = 0xFF112233
Direction = 0x44556677
ID        = 0x8899
```

but manually memcpy, the data I retrieved is correct

```
NodeType  = 0xAA  
Group     = 0xBBCCDDEE
Direction = 0xFF112233
ID        = 0x4455
```

it seems like the first set it tries to copy 4 bytes into the NodeType.

Am I doing the pointer copy wrong? or could this be a device / HW problem?

Comment: note : pointer arithmetic of type of `void *` is invalid.

Comment: ... but supported as an extension by GCC.

Comment: @unwind yes, That way in handy indeed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is free to add padding between the members of a structure, so that each member is aligned to whatever is natural for your platform - here, it looks like 32 bits. Try printing `sizeof(tsTargetNode)`, and dumping that many bytes from an initialized `tsTargetNode` to see how the fields are laid out.

You haven't said what compiler you're using, but there will be a compiler-specific way to disable padding for your structure. If you do that, its memory layout will match the buffer.

Comment: im using a gcc as the compiler. and i tried checking sizeof, it returns 16 (bytes). but im sure my struct isnt 16 bytes. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to look into the compiler-specific padding.

Comment: @codex10 Keep in mind that packing the struct to remove the padding comes with a cost: It usually requires compiler specific syntax, which makes porting more difficult. Also, on most platforms accessing packed stucts is slower and/or requires more program memory.

Comment: Sum `sizeof` for each member - you should get 11, so there are 5 bytes of padding. For gcc, you can use [`__attribute__((packed))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) or [`#pragma pack`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html). It's true that all this is both compiler-specific and has platform-specific performance/code-size/bus-error pitfalls. Writing member-by-member (de)serialization is safe, portable and unbearably tedious and error-prone. Your choice!

Comment: I'll go with packing the struct for now. We're restricted to follow a set of network protocols so sending incorrect sized packets usually causes problems in the board and in the receiving server. Thanks for the tips; ill keep the performance issues in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your compiler to "pack" the struct:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
   u8int  NodeType;
   u32int Group;
   u32int Direction;
   u16int ID;

} tsTargetNode;
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Type-Attributes.html